# In Excel, can picture be inserted into a specific range of cells without exceeding the cell ranges width OR height, but also without distorting image?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create an 'Add logo' button into my excel sheet. It is essentially working, the only issue is I want to make sure the inserted picture:

a) Does not distort the original aspect ratio

b) Does not exceed the height of the range of cells it is designed to fit in (Rows 11 to 13)

c) Does not exceed the width of the range of cells it is designed to fit in (Columns Y to AL)

I am using the code below. I have worked out that setting the LockAspectRatio = msoFalse fixes problems b) and c) but not a). And that LockAspectRatio = msoTrue fixes problems a), but not b) and c). I am looking for a solution that fixes all 3.

```
Sub Add_logo()

Dim fNameAndPath As Variant
Dim img As Picture
fNameAndPath = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Select picture to be imported")
If fNameAndPath = False Then Exit Sub
Set img = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(fNameAndPath)

    With img
    .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
    .Name = "Logo"
    .Left = ActiveSheet.Range("y11").Left
    .Top = ActiveSheet.Range("y11").Top
    .Width = ActiveSheet.Range("Y11:AL11").Width
    .Height = ActiveSheet.Range("Y11:Y13").Height
    .PrintObject = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Set `LockAspectRatio` to `msoTrue`, set the width of the image to the width of the columns, then compare the height of the image to the height of the rows and if it is greater, reduce the image to the desired height.